# Programmatically allow PDF to save

Tags: pdf

I am programmatically populating a PDF created with Livecycle (plus extended features through Adobe Acrobat).  After populating the fields, I want to allow users to edit and save.

```
private void XMLFieldPopulate(PdfReader reader, Dictionary<string, string> listOfValues, PdfStamper stamper)
    {
        AcroFields form = reader.AcroFields;
        XfaForm xfaform = form.Xfa;
        XmlNode node = xfaform.DatasetsNode;
        XmlNodeList list = node.ChildNodes;

        do
        {
            node = list.Item(0);
            list = node.ChildNodes;
        } while (node.Name != "topmostSubform");

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {

            string attribute = list[i].Name;
            string value = string.Empty;

            value = listOfValues.First(x => x.Key == attribute).Value;
                list[i].InnerText = value;
        }

        xfaform.FillXfaForm(node);
        xfaform.SetXfa(stamper.Writer);
```

I can get PDF to populate and have it edited, but it won't allow save.

Comment: If you fill the forms in manually, does it allow you to save? If not then you're pdf might be missing a property to allow you to save.

Comment: prior to the pdf template being filled in, it does allow me to save, but once it automatically populates, it allows me to edit but not save.

Comment: Do you create the stamper in append mode?